# Set the ACL specifying the worker processes that are allowed to receive I/O on the request queue

Tags: c++, winapi, acl

I'm playing with WinHTTP Server API 2.0 and I'm trying following steps(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364672(v=vs.85).aspx):

- Create the request queue and specify the name.
- Configure the request queue using the `HttpSetRequestQueueProperty` function.
- Query the request queue configuration parameters using the `HttpQueryRequestQueueProperty` function.
- Create URL Groups and associates them with a request queue.
- **Set the ACL specifying the worker processes that are allowed to receive I/O on the request queue**.
- Call `HttpWaitForDemandStart` to delay the instantiation of worker processes until the first request arrives on the request queue.

Could anybody help with step:

> Set the ACL specifying the worker processes that are allowed to receive I/O on the request queue

I'm not sure what does that really mean (I've never used ACL API), but I assume I need to call `::GetNamedSecurityInfo()` at some point of time to modify it then:

```
    if (NO_ERROR == ::HttpCreateRequestQueue(HTTPAPI_VERSION_2,
                                             requestQueueName,
                                             0,
                                             HTTP_CREATE_REQUEST_QUEUE_FLAG_CONTROLLER,
                                             &m_requestQueue))
      // setup queue 
      if (NO_ERROR == ::HttpCreateUrlGroup(m_sessionId, &m_groupId, 0))
      {
        HTTP_BINDING_INFO bindingInfo{ 1, m_requestQueue };
        if (NO_ERROR == ::HttpSetUrlGroupProperty(m_groupId, 
                                                  HttpServerBindingProperty,
                                                  &bindingInfo, 
                                                  sizeof(bindingInfo)))
        {
           m_localUrl = (NO_ERROR == (::HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup(m_groupId, localUrl.c_str(), 0, 0)));
           m_globalUrl = (NO_ERROR == (::HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup(m_groupId, globalUrl.c_str(), 0, 0)));

           PACL pacl = NULL;
           PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR securityDescriptor = NULL;
           DWORD result = ::GetNamedSecurityInfo(requestQueueName, 
                                                 SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, 
                                                 SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                                 NULL, 
                                                 NULL, 
                                                 NULL, 
                                                 &pacl, 
                                                 &securityDescriptor);
           // it (result != 0) fails when passing various SE_OBJECT_TYPEs
        }
     }
```

---

Comment: not a *ACL* but Security Descriptor in `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` .this is like when you create any kernel object, nothing special. you can and pass 0. for allow access to any - can set 0 DACL is SD. and you not need modify then after create. you need just set what you want as SD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set the ACL specifying the worker processes that are allowed to
>   receive I/O on the request queue

look for else one note:

> The named request queue is created with the **HttpCreateRequestQueue**
>   function. When the request queue is created, the application specifies
>   the ACL in the **pSecurityAttribute** parameter. The ACL, which can only
>   be set when the request queue is created, allows worker processes to
>   open the request queue, receive requests, and send responses. By
>   default, processes are not allowed to open a request queue unless they
>   have been granted permission in the ACL. Applications do not require
>   administrative privileges to create the request queue.

so really you can (but not must, this is optional) create and initialize some security descriptor and pass it to HttpCreateRequestQueue function via `In_opt_ PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES pSecurityAttributes` - here absolute nothing special, the `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` used in any kernel object create api. say [`CreateEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) for example (here first parameter).

how initialize it, for whom grant access - this is already open question - the border case - allow this for all:

```
    ULONG cb = MAX_SID_SIZE;
    PSID UntrustedLabelSid = (PSID)alloca(MAX_SID_SIZE);
    if (CreateWellKnownSid(WinUntrustedLabelSid, 0, UntrustedLabelSid, &cb))
    {
        PACL Sacl = (PACL)alloca(cb += sizeof(ACL) + sizeof(ACE_HEADER) + sizeof(ACCESS_MASK));
        InitializeAcl(Sacl, cb, ACL_REVISION);
        if (AddMandatoryAce(Sacl, ACL_REVISION, 0, 0, UntrustedLabelSid))
        {
            SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
            InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
            SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
            SetSecurityDescriptorSacl(&sd, TRUE, Sacl, FALSE);

            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), &sd, FALSE };

            if (NO_ERROR == HttpCreateRequestQueue(HTTPAPI_VERSION_2,
                requestQueueName,
                &sa,
                HTTP_CREATE_REQUEST_QUEUE_FLAG_CONTROLLER,
                &m_requestQueue))
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

---

as alternative, we can use and [*string-format security descriptor*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379570(v=vs.85).aspx) and then convert it with [`ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376401(v=vs.85).aspx) for example:

```
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), 0, FALSE };
    ULONG dwError;
    if (ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(
        L"D:NO_ACCESS_CONTROLS:(ML;;;;;LW)", 
        SDDL_REVISION_1, &sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, 0))
    {           
        dwError = HttpCreateRequestQueue(HTTPAPI_VERSION_2,
            requestQueueName,
            &sa,
            HTTP_CREATE_REQUEST_QUEUE_FLAG_CONTROLLER,
            &m_requestQueue);

        LocalFree(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor);
    }
    else
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }
```

here `"D:NO_ACCESS_CONTROLS:(ML;;;;;LW)"` allow all access to all - `NO_ACCESS_CONTROLS` and `LW` - LowLabel. (not untrusted as in first example)

another variant (only for example) use say next string:

`"D:(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GRGX;;;BU)(A;;GRGX;;;AC)S:(ML;;;;;LW)"`

here we allow `GENERIC_ALL` (`GA`) to *System* (`SY`) and *Administrators* (`BA`) and `GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_EXECUTE` for *Users* (`BU`) and *ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES* (`AC`)

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works! Yeah, I read that note while I was digging out, but the list of steps had totally confused me in the end. I don't create and initialize security descriptors every day - this is something I always rejected to practice... seems like I need to do it finally.

Comment: @kEst86 - i add example also how use Security Descriptor String Format - may be this will be more easy